# Access chrome://flags or chrome://gpu

Tags: javascript, qt, embedded-linux, chromium, qtwebengine

I am using a browser on an embedded system and I would like to check if hardware acceleration flags and so on are enabled. Usually I do this kind of checks by accessing "chrome://flags" or "chrome://gpu".

The browser is a QtWebEngine-based one. when I try to access one of those pages by using location.href I get:

"Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://flags/"

Also I am not able to open them by using an iframe

Can anyone help?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed to access local resources from `javascript` or site content like links.
Chromium issue is referred [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=595339) 
There is one but **dangerous** work around which I'm not recommending to use : providing `--disable-web-security` flag through `QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS` environmental var or as argument to the browser you are running. But it will not just allow you to open those urls but will disable lots of security features which I believe is not what you wont.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the answer from [j2ko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751535/j2ko), to check the GPU acceleration flags, you need to:

1. Set the environment variable with `QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS=--disable-web-security`
2. Set the environment variable `QTWEBENGINE_REMOTE_DEBUGGING=8080`
3. Open a Chromium Browser and access the address `http://127.0.0.1:8080`
4. Access the console tab and enter the JavaScript command `location.href = "chrome://gpu/"`
5. The `chrome://gpu/` will open on your QT view. In case you extended the `QWebEnginePage` class, just ensure you not have overwritten the method [`acceptNavigationRequest()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#acceptNavigationRequest) blocking the navigation.

Additionally, you can disable hardware acceleration by setting the `QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS=--disable-gpu` or `QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--disable-web-security --disable-gpu"`.

Related to:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/656687/confirm-correctly-working-of-hardware-acceleration-in-chrome-windows-7